# .text() and .val() in select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple HTML Markup as shown below :-

```
<select id="select1">
<option></option>
<option>AAA</option>
<option>BBB</option>
<option>CCC</option>
<option>DDD</option>
<option>EEE</option>
</select>  

<textarea style="height:150px;width:150px" id="t1"></textarea>
<textarea style="height:150px;width:150px" id="t2"></textarea>
```

Jquery Code :-

```
$("#select1").change(function(){
  $("#t1").val($(this).text());            // 1st
});

$("#select1").change(function(){
  $("#t2").val($(this).val());             // 2nd
});
```

My Questions :-

1.) When I use 1st jquery code using `.text()` ,the text of all the options in select tag are shown instead I was expecting that only selected option text should be displayed in 1st jquery code.

2.) When I use 2nd jquery code using `.val()` ,in this case `.val()` is working even though I don't expect that it will work because there no values in my dropdown, but it is working and giving selected option text as value.

**Above written are my two questions.I just want a explanation why above 1st and 2nd jquery code is behaving unexpectedly.**

Fiddle Link :- http://jsfiddle.net/mzfmxsd8/

Thanks in Advance..!!

Comment: Neither 1 or 2 is a question... What is your question? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you write val($(this).text()); ofcourse all value of #select1 will be displayed.

Comment: @naomik...plz read carefully..my questions are written above...the jquery code in not behaving as expected...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You need to find the `option` that is selected, then find its text like `$("#t1").val($(this).find(':selected').text());`. The [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method will return the text content of all the descendants of the current element. So it fetches the text of all the options in the select.

2) If there is no value then the text content is considered as the value

[option.value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

> The textual content of this attribute represents the label explaining
>   the option. If it is not defined, its default value is the text
>   content of the element.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sq4675xo/)

Comment: You copied my answer, edited yours and put it as your own. Nonetheless, this is the answer. @Exception.

Comment: @sahbeewah based on the timestap I could say you copied my answer

Comment: @Exception that is how the implementation of `value` attribute done... see the [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) for value attribute

Comment: @ArunPJohny You're right - you could. It's easy to manipulate StackOverflow's editing grace period and make it seem that way. I'm glad you liked my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the select element. When you call `.text()` on it, it retrieves all of its descendants (the option elements) and extracts the text from it, which is what you're seeing.

When option values don't have a value attribute, the text inside it becomes its value. And thus the value of the select element is the selected option value.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are trying to display text of options by selecting all options of select element. As you want to display text of only selected option, you have to select only selected option and display its text inside textarea.

Here's the code:

```
$("#select1").change(function(){
  $("#t1").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());            // 1st
});
```

Comment: @Kartikeya I have provided the explanation too..!! Please go through it.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to get selected option text

```
$("#select1").change(function(){
    $("#t1").val($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});

$("#select1").change(function(){
   $("#t2").val($(this).val());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mzfmxsd8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected value:

`this[this.selectedIndex].value`

Use that in the lambda. Reading the jQuery source will find your answer for you. In particular you should look into the `val` method if you want to know the internals.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LnL3trzj/

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the below code

```
$("#select1").change(function(){
  $("#t1").val($("#select1 option:selected").text());           
});
```